# iOS - Where To Check Corresponding UI Element Given A Hex Value ID

Tags: ios

I keep on getting this error:

```
Cannot find an outgoing row head for incoming head UIButton:0x17fd8620.Width{id: 1056}, which should never happen.'
```

I've searched a solution for this, but they say it's the aspect ratio that's causing the problem. Then I temporarily removed the aspect ratio constraints for every UIButton on that view, but still I get this error.

I want to know how or where could I check the UIButton that it states given this 0x17fd8620 (I don't know what it's called).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "*hex value*" was actually the object's (in your case, the `UIButton`) location in the memory, like those you can see in the debug area:

[image: debug area]

To find more info regarding that object, use the **lldb console** in the debug area on the left, just like what you do within the source: (I use `UILabel` as an example)

[image: lldb]

Those detail should be enough for you to identify your object.

Or, you can set up an "**Exception Breakpoint**" to find out where went wrong.